# RSS Feed Import Returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, rss

I have a block of PHP that is talking to my RSS feed and importing it. The problem is, it's decided to return a 500 Internal Server Error and I can't seem to figure out why. I've used this code with a previous feed and it worked perfectly. But with this new feed it breaks. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```
    <?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('http://guiltyfeminist.com/rss');
    $cnt=0;

    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $itemRSS = array ( 
    'maintitle' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'enclosure' => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url'),
    );
    ?>
    <div class="showcontent">
        <div class="contentleft">
        <img src="<?php echo $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd', 'image')->item(0)->getAttribute('href'); ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="contentright">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo $itemRSS['link']; ?>"><?php echo $itemRSS['maintitle']; ?></a></h2>
            <p><strong>Duration</strong> <?php echo $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd', 'duration')->item(0)->nodeValue; ?></p>
            <p><strong>Published</strong> <?php echo $itemRSS['date']; ?></p>
            <audio controls>
              <source src="<?php echo $itemRSS['enclosure']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $cnt ++; } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is working fine. you can try same code on another PC

Comment: I tried, but I get this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null in..." 

and it points to this line: `'enclosure' => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url'),`

Any ideas how I can resolve this. I know it says a null reference but how can I fix the code above to prevent this.